# Declaring static arrays in php

Tags: php

I am new to php. I was wondering how I could declare a static array in php. Here is what I would do in C. How is the corresponding php code for it?

```
char a[][] = { (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) };
```

From what I read it has to be something like this -

```
$a = array( 1 => array(1,1), 2 => array(1,2), ... );
```

Is this correct? If so it sucks :) I hope I am wrong.

Thanks,
- Pav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already found the way to do it natively.

Another option would be to declare your data as JSON (a very concise and human-friendly format).  This could be either in a separate file bundled with your app, or directly in your code in a string.  Then parse the JSON at runtime.  Since PHP isn't exactly known for speed, this may or may not make your noticeably app slower to start.

Comment: is telling to use something like: `$matrix = json_decode('[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3], [2,1],[2,2],[2,3], [3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]');`. You may use extra spaces for clarity.

Comment: Thanks that is another way to go I guess. I come from C and so was really miss the C style. Also what do you mean by php is not known for speed? Its better than Java right? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

you have it already figured out in your question.

One thing I would add is that you do not need to explicitly define the keys if you are intending to use a zero based array, this is assumed and can be done like so...

```
$a = array(array(1,1),array(1,2), ... );
```

You can also use what is called associative arrays which use string keys and you define them the same way you do in your example, except use strings instead of numbers...

```
$ass_array = array( 'array_1' => array(1,1), 'array_2' => array(1,2), ... );
```

you would then call your associative array like this...

```
$ass_array['array_1'];
```

Also, if you want to append single items to an array (for example in a loop to load an array)...

```
$ass_array[] = $item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to [jondavidjohn's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559561/declaring-static-arrays-in-php/4559605#4559605), you could just write a quick script to grab your list of values and generate the array statement for you.

No need to care how verbose the syntax is then. If the task is long and repetitious enough to care, don't do it by hand. :)